# Why does most website use %2F instead of forward slash(/) on http return url

Tags: php, codeigniter, http

I have been searching this on google but I couldn't find the answer. Hope somebody can answer it.

Now, On my login page, I have added a return value on my query string:

`http://www.example.com/login?return=http://www.example.com/dashboard`

after the user has logged in, it will be redirected to `http://www.example.com/dashboard` as it is the return value by using:

**PHP Core**

```
 <?php
     $return_url = (string) $_GET['return'];
    header('Location:' . $return_url);
 ?>
```

**Codeigniter**

```
 <?php 
    $return_url = $this->input->get('return');
    redirect( $return_url );
 ?>
```

On my end, the above return url works fine. But, I am just curious why do most websites use %2 instead of / just like below:

`http://www.example.com/login?return=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2dashboard`

Are there any reason for this?

Comment: this is url escaping and you're required to perform it, php does url unescaping for you, this is why it works

Comment: It's called URL-encoding.  It's technically required, though often browsers can figure out what you meant (depending on the characters used).  But it's best to explicitly define what you meant rather than rely on the browser to figure it out, since it might not conclude what you think it should.

Comment: Why downvote? Is there no place for developers to ask question here?

Comment: Have a look here http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php and here http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: @wolfgang1983 thank you. we'll check it out